# problema com select case

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case

estou fazendo select com case comparando status diferentes de um mesmo campo e contabilizando-os em colunas separadas. O problema é que a primeira coluna fica `NULL` até a lista da segunda terminar a contagem. Depois isso é invertido.

Minha query é a seguinte:

```
select
    case when cor.status = 35 then count(cor.uid) end as finalizadas,
    case when cor.status = 50 then count(cor.uid) end as canceladas_motorista,
    mot.nome || ' ' || mot.sobrenome as nome,
    mot.celular,
    mot.email
from motoristas mot, corridas cor
where...
```

segue exemplo de resultado:

[image: resultado da consulta]

Alguma ajuda, por favor?

Comment: *"O problema é que a primeira coluna fica NULL até a lista da segunda terminar a contagem. Depois isso é invertido"* João, não entendi, pode explicar melhor? Como assim terminar a contagem? O resultado vem todo de uma vez, não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: Eu ajustei a postagem ali com uma foto. Acabei não me expressando corretamente no início, mas acho que com a imagem vai ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: agora sim entendi :)  você quer na mesma linha finalizadas  e canceladas né?

Comment: exatamente! Esse é o ponto. Vou tentar ser mais objetivos nas próximas

Comment: só uma dúvida, não está no seu select, mas joins estão sendo feitos certo? Se não for por `inner join`, você está fazendo no `where` certo? Senão o resultado vai sair errado

Comment: sim, estou fazendo no where!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só tem que ir incrementando o resultado de ambas as colunas:

```
SELECT      SUM(CASE WHEN cor.status = 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS finalizadas
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN cor.status = 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS canceladas_motorista
        ,   mot.nome || ' ' || mot.sobrenome                    AS nome
        ,   mot.celular
        ,   mot.email
FROM        motoristas mot, corridas cor
WHERE       ...
GROUP BY    mot.nome || ' ' || mot.sobrenome
        ,   mot.celular
        ,   mot.email
```

Comment: Voltei pra responder e a resposta já estava aqui. Fiz exatamente isso e solucionou meu problema! Agradeçço muito, de qualquer forma.

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens! Aproveite e dê um UP nas respostas que você considerou úteis! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também fazer uma *subquery* para calcular cada status por motorista, assim:

```
select 
  (select count(cor.uid)
     from corridas cor
    where cor.idMotorista = mot.idMotorista
     and cor.status = 35) as finalizadas,
  (select count(cor.uid)
     from corridas cor
    where cor.idMotorista = mot.idMotorista
     and cor.status = 50) as canceladas_motorista,
mot.nome  
from motoristas mot
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29af1/28

Comment: Consegui a resolução em outra resposta já. Mas agradeço a ajuda. Estou tentando descobrir como e encerra tópico ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Encerrar tópico? Não precisa, basta escolher uma resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar esta consulta em uma *subconsulta*, agrupando o retorno pelos campos que não são somatórios; assim, trará para o usuário o resultado final.

```
select sum(finalizadas), sum(canceladas_motorista), nome, celular, email
(select
    case when cor.status = 35 then count(cor.uid) end as finalizadas,
    case when cor.status = 50 then count(cor.uid) end as canceladas_motorista,
    mot.nome || ' ' || mot.sobrenome as nome,
    mot.celular as celular,
    mot.email as email
from motoristas mot, corridas cor
where ...) as tabela_subconsulta
group by nome, celular, email
```

Comment: Vou tentar isso e respondo na sequência. Obrigado